# Spring data mongo db not creating some collections

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I am using spring boot starter **2.1.6** and spring-data-mongo starter version is **2.1.6.RELEASE**.

Whenever the server starts i understood spring boot mongo creates the collection schema. For some reason spring boot mongo does not create collection schema for some specific collection. These collections are all the time same ones.

But when i create programatically by myself they are created without error or warning.

```
mongoTemplate.createCollection("collectionName");
```

> I would like to know how to find out why spring boot is not able to
>   create these specific collections.

For example below is one of the collection which is not created automatically by spring boot.

```
@Document(collection = "subscription_histories")
public class SubscriptionHistoryModel extends AbstractModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4424861457985412905L;

    @NotNull
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    @Field("customer")
    private CustomerModel customer;

    @NotNull
    @Field("subscription_from")
    private Instant subscriptionFrom;

    @NotNull
    @Field("subscription_to")
    private Instant subscriptionTo;

    public CustomerModel getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(CustomerModel customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Instant getSubscriptionFrom() {
        return subscriptionFrom;
    }

    public void setSubscriptionFrom(Instant subscriptionFrom) {
        this.subscriptionFrom = subscriptionFrom;
    }

    public Instant getSubscriptionTo() {
        return subscriptionTo;
    }

    public void setSubscriptionTo(Instant subscriptionTo) {
        this.subscriptionTo = subscriptionTo;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling on this issue for past 2 days as well. Finally found why was this happening.
So if you're using docker for the mongodb and mongodb express. Idk for some reason the data is being stored locally and accessed from there and not the mongodb docker container. I've also installed mongodb locally and was trying to run using docker as well.

So, you must check if there are any other places where your mongodb service might be running and your program might be referring to that place!